# Graphs invariant to permutations of vertices

Tags: graphs, machine-learning

I am reading a paper on [Semi Supervised Learning](http://talukdar.net/papers/adsorption_ecml09.pdf) and I am confused about a term. The paper talks about graphs that are invariant to permutations of the vertices. Can somebody explain or perhaps give an example? Is it same a regular graphs?

Comment: I believe this is called a [Vertex-Transitive Graph](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vertex-transitive_graph). As explained in the article every v.t. graph is regular, but not every regular graph is v.t.

Comment: Are the graphs invariant under *all* permutations of the vertices? The only such graphs are the empty and complete graphs. Vertex-transitive graphs have automorphisms which send any given vertex to any other given vertex, so all vertices are "the same" when considered on their own. In particular, they have the same degree.